# Converting a frequency (time related) into a date (due date)

Tags: ms-access

need some guidance and suggestions on a solution to my requirement. I'm not an expert, just a keep amateur.

I have an Access database which manages and reports various verifications. Verification are entered with details including a frequency required i.e. daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly annually. Verification results are entered by selecting the relevant verification and entering details and selecting a specific asset. There are multiple assets and multiple verifications, some of which are required more frequently than others.

I want to be able to convert the Verification frequency to a date for each, depending on what frequency was selected when setting up required verification.

Ultimately I want to be able to report complete/incomplete verifications against each asset (or all) according to the required verification frequency.

What is the best way to structure that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Record a start time as DateTime and the interval expressed in days, weeks, months, quarters, or years (`"d", "ww", "m", "q", "yyyy"`) and a count of these (integer).

Then use `DateAdd(interval, count, StartDate)` to obtain the later verification dates.